# Space and Time complexity of matrix_in_spiral_order(matrix)

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm reading Elements of Programming interviews in Python (Aziz, Lee, Prakash) and don't understand the space and time complexity for one of their algorithms. The question asked to return a matrix in spiral order (example [here](http://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2016/11/print-matrix-in-spiral-order.html)).

At the end of the algorithm, the authors state that this is O(n^2) time complexity, and O(1) space complexity. It's been a few years since I've formally studied complexity, so I don't understand either of these claims. In the code below we build a brand new array with all the elements in spiral order, which would lead me to believe this is not an in place operation, and would therefore have space complexity of O(nxn).

For the time complexity I am also confused. We only iterate through the 2D array once for each element. Wouldn't it therefore be considered O(n)? How is this different than just flattening this into a 1D array and going through it once?

```
def matrix_in_spiral_order(square_matrix):
    SHIFT = ((0,1),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,0))
    direction = x = y = 0
    spiral_ordering = []

    for _ in range(len(square_matrix)**2):
        spiral_ordering.append(square_matrix[x][y])
        square_matrix[x][y] = 0
        next_x,next_y = x + SHIFT[direction][0], y+ SHIFT[direction][1]
        if (next_x not in range(len(square_matrix)) or next_y not in range(
              len(square_matrix)) or square_matrix[next_x][next_y] == 0):
            direction = (direction +1) & 3
            next_x, next_y = x+ SHIFT[direction][0], y + SHIFT[direction][1]
        x,y = next_x, next_y
    return spiral_ordering
```

I ended up solving this recursively using a different solution, but still want to understand how they arrived at their analysis of the above algorithm.

Comment: Seems pretty terrible.. destroys the original matrix, breaks if any cell already contains zero.. I suppose it's O(n^2) if you define n as the length of one dimension of the matrix. I don't see how it's O(1) space though. I suspect you'd need to ask Aziz, Lee, or Prakash to get their explanation.

Comment: Excellent point. I went back to check if they laid out initial assumptions for the input, and they had not. Seems a bit sloppy.

Edit: My mistake, they did indeed say that the assumption was no 0 entries in the array. It was just buried in the initial explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that their definition of N is the length of a side of the matrix while your definition of N is the product of the sides of the matrix. This seems like six of one, half a dozen of another, although it's open for debate as to which is less misleading.

As for the space complexity, once again, it sounds like their interpretation is that the returned result doesn't count. This is fair enough, but it does need to be made explicit, and I think your intuition as far as expressing doubts about both of their claims is sound.

As a side note, I agree with @Blorgbeard that the algorithm they've provided is less than exemplary.

Comment: Ok great, makes sense. I suspected it might be something like that, but they weren't really clear with the case of the n (n vs. N). If it's just a definition problem I can live with that. Thank you sir.

Comment: Right, my understanding is that they could have been more explicit, but at the end of the day, you're both saying the same thing. Sometimes it takes a bit of flexibility to intuit what they're going for when they make a statement like "O(1) space" (we can assume the authors are aware that they've created an in-memory structure equal to the size of the input). Some problems specify that a new structure needs to be returned and it seems common to ignore that and compute Big O in a way that disregards the "in-place vs don't mutate" spec.